# IOS Custom UINavigationBar - barButtonItems receiving touch out of bounds

Tags: ios, uibutton, custom-controls, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I implemented this custom NavigationBar Class for my project: [Video with Issue](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gi7s8wmf54vl7hf/navbarQuestion.mov?v=1mci)

```
#import "PTTNavigationBar.h"
@implementation PTTNavigationBar

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

}
    return self;
}


// Overriding drawRect: perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    UIImage *navBarImage = UIIMAGE_NAMED( kNavBarBackGroundImage );
    [navBarImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, NAVBAR_SIZE.width , NAVBAR_SIZE.height)];

    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

}

- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {

    //[self setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:-12 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    CGRect frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width , NAVBAR_SIZE.height);
   [self layoutSubviews];

    return newSize;
}


-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
   {
       CGRect frame = view.frame;
       frame.origin.y = 6;
       view.frame = frame;
    }


}

@end
```

anyone can help me with this??
thx

Comment: How you are adding the barButtonItems ? are they custom buttons ?

Comment: its a back button. a default one

Comment: That is a default feature in iOS, u can check in setting app. If you really want to restrict the touch then my answer will work.

Comment: @prasaddevadiga what you mean for setting app and default feature, sorry?

Comment: u can check in iPhone setting app. its a feature of in navigation bar buttons.

Comment: @prasaddevadiga I cant find that setting could you please address me there (which section I can find it?). But your solution is working anyway! ^^

Comment: What I meant by setting app is your iPhone setting. You can find that in your iPhone/simulator, called "Settings". There you can find the same behaviour. If you want to restrict the touch then you can make use of my answer.

Comment: if my solution is working as per your requirements then you can make use that only.

Comment: I accepted you answer but I wanted to try to understand ( and im still looking for this setting!!) also for sake of other users that may be wondering the same. maybe you could implement your answer? ^^

Comment: Looks like you misunderstood me. Let me be more clear and straightforward, if you want to restrict the touch within the bounds of navigationBarButton then you need to customise it as I told in my solution. Otherwise the touch area of navigationBarButton is more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are adding custom buttons to leftBarButton through code.

The following code should restrict the touch inside the bounds of barButtonItem

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
[button addTarget:self action: @selector(handleBackButton)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height)];
[view addSubview:button];

UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:view];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
```